# Loading local .png and .mp3 files in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: image, audio, actionscript, loading, flashdevelop

I am writing a program in Actionscript using FlashDevelop. Using URLRequest, I am loading image and sound files perfectly fine when the program is run through FlashDevelop. The files are located in bin with my HTML and swf files. However, when I run it using the browser (Chrome), the sound files works fine but the image does not load. I would think that it is a problem with the path, but the mp3 plays just fine, so I know that it can't be that.

Any ideas about what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ad Blocker Extension in Chrome, then you need to turn of it or give images names which are not blockable in Ad Blocker.

Comment: I got it to work by adding the Loader to the Main Sprite. But I need to Load images in another class where I can't solve this problem that way? It must have been a security issue then because it wasn't the paths. Any ideas about how to get around this?